# Can comment delimiters be typeset in a style different from commentstyle?

Tags: listings, delimiters

Using `listings`, I'm trying to typeset single-line comments in a very specific way: although whatever follows should be typeset according to the value passed to the `commentstyle` key, the opening delimiter should be typeset in the identifier style (i.e. that of the "normal code").

I've been playing around with the different *types* (`s`,`m`,`l`) and the `i` prefix of `morecomment` offered by the `listings` package, to no avail. Any idea?

**Edit**: Of course, one requirement is that I shouldn't have to alter the listing itself to to obtain the desired output; introducing delimiters in the listing is cheating :)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset%
{%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\itshape\color{blue},
    morecomment=[s]{\%\%}{\^^M},
}

\begin{document}

\lstset{}
\begin{lstlisting}
confusion=Inf %% this is a comment
\end{lstlisting}

How can I get the opening comment delimiter (\texttt{\%\%}) to be typeset,
not in blue, but in the default colour (black)?

\end{document}
```

[image: output screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of experimentation, I still couldn't figure out how to get the desired output using `morecomment`; I ended up using `moredelim` (with the `il` prefix) instead, and I defined a `\processDelimiter` macro to process each occurence of my `%%` delimiter in the listing. See below (I left a few comments in my code).

This solution is mostly okay but suffers from a really puzzling spacing problem, which I'll probably document in another question (**edit**: see [Weird spacing issue using listings delimiters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148939/weird-spacing-issue-using-listings-delimiters)).

There may be better ways of getting the desired output, but I'm at my wit's end.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

% switch to keep track of context (in a comment or not)
\newif\ifcom\comfalse


\makeatletter

% This is what happens if a delimiter is encountered
\def\processDelimiter{%
    \ifcom%                     % In this case, we're already in a comment.
    \else                       % Otherwise, we just started a comment;
        \global\comtrue%        % set the switch to true and
        {\lst@basicstyle\%\%}%  % typeset the delimiter in the basic style.
    \fi
    \lst@commentstyle%          % In any case, apply the comment style.
}

% Reset the switch at each End-Of-Line character.
\lst@AddToHook{EOL}{\global\comfalse}

\makeatother


\lstset{
    basicstyle   = \ttfamily,
    commentstyle = \itshape\color{blue},
    moredelim    = [il][\processDelimiter]{\%\%},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
x:=1000; %% this is a comment %% still in a comment
x:=x/2; %% another comment
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it's possible with the `comment` key, but you could (ab)use `escapeinside`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset%
{%
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
%    commentstyle=\itshape\color{blue},
%    morecomment=[s]{\%\%}{\^^M},
    escapeinside={\%\%}{\^^M},
    escapebegin={\%\%\itshape\color{blue}\obeyspaces}
}
\begin{document}

\lstset{}
\begin{lstlisting}
confusion=Inf %% this is a comment
confusion=Inf %%this is  a comment
confusion=Inf %% this is $\alpha$ comment
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

(As you pointed out yourself, `\obeyspaces` should be at the end in order to have all spaces after the comment marker honoured.)

The downside is that TeX text will be typeset instead of being output verbatim:

[image: listings comments]

Comment: Hey thanks. I'm going to ponder whether your approach is a good idea in my case; escaping to LaTeX may be problematic. Side note: putting `\obeyspaces` at the end seems to obviate the limitation you mentioned; try `escapebegin={\%\%\itshape\color{blue}\obeyspaces}`

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't afford to escape to LaTeX. I had to resort to other means. Thanks anyway.