# Is it possible to replace text which has blank spaces using `literate` of the `listings` package?

Tags: formatting, listings, code

Please consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
    columns=flexible,
    literate=
      {Public Class}{{Public Class\color{red}}}{12}
      {.Object}{{.\color{red}Object\color{black}}}{6}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
Public Class Example

.Object = A
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

I would like to have `Example` in red, but I am not able to do it.

I thought

```
{Public Class}{{Public Class\color{red}}}{12}
```

was going to fill any sequence of characters *after* `Public Class`, like

```
{.Object}{{.\color{red}Object}}{6}
```

[image]

(Note that I removed `\color{black}` and `= A` was filled with red.)

**Important** `Example` can be changed i.e. the red color should work for *any* sequence of characters *of the same line* of `Public Class`. This effect is removed in the next line.

**EDIT** Oh, I realized that the blank space of `{Public Class}` is the problem. I will search if this is a duplicate, though.

**EDIT 2** I could not find a duplicate. I also edited the question because I forgot to add `columns=flexible`, which makes the things a bit more difficult, because as [@Robert pointed out](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531668/is-it-possible-to-replace-text-which-has-blank-spaces-using-literate-of-the-l?noredirect=1#comment1344339_531668) doing `{Public\ Class}` solves the problem, but adding `columns=flexible` does not work anymore.

Comment: `{Public\ Class}` ?

Comment: @Robert I thought the same; but there is a problem with the correct spacing, isn't it?

Comment: yes, the whole string is printed as one token that is centred within the space given by the last argument, but this has nothing to do with the space, but is how the `literate` feature works -- try eg. `{.IIIIII}{{.\color{red}IIIIII\color{black}}}{6}`

Comment: @Robert there is another problem. In the document I am using `columns=flexible` which shrinks the characters width, so `{Public\ Class}` does not work anymore.

Comment: yes, there's one more group involved in the case of `flexible`, so the color setting doesn't get carried over. Maybe instead of `literate`, you could use this: `moredelim=**[il][\PublicClass]{Public\ Class}` with `\newcommand\PublicClass{Public Class\color{red}}`

Comment: @Robert it worked. Many thanks! Do you want to post it as an answer? Do you want to contact the owner of the package and communicate this to him?

Comment: what would you think should be communicated? I'd say this use of `literate` is somewhat outside its original purpose, so I'm not sure there's anything worthy of a report here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the `literate` key, you could use `moredelim` (building on [this trick](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148939/7674)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{
    columns=flexible,
    moredelim=**[il][\PublicClass]{Public\ Class},
}
\newcommand\PublicClass{Public Class\color{red}}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
Public Class Example
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```