# listings: Highlight one-line delim without the delimiter itself

Tags: listings, highlighting, delimiters

I would like to use a one-line delimiter (with `[l]` parameter), but without highlighting the delimiter itself; something like

sqlite> **.open ex2.db**

What follows `sqlite>` should get highlighted but not `sqlite>` itself. I found solutions only for multi-line delimiters. I'm not able to make them work for one-line delimiters:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{newtxtt} 

\newcommand{\functionHighlightAfterSqlite}[1]{\ttfamily\bfseries\color{red}{#1}}

\lstnewenvironment{lstSqlite}
{\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries,
    language=SQL,    
    moredelim=*[l][\functionHighlightAfterSqlite]{sqlite>},
    moredelim=[l][\ttfamily\bfseries\color{red}]{...>}} } % highlights delimiter
{}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstSqlite}
sqlite> .open ex2.db
sqlite> select *
   ...> from tab;
Git|1
SQLite|3
\end{lstSqlite}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same trick as described in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148886/21891):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{newtxtt} 

\newcommand\styleAfterSqlitePrompt{%
    \ttfamily\bfseries\color{red}%
}

% switch to keep track of context (in a command or not)
\newif\ifcom\comfalse


\makeatletter

% This is what happens if a delimiter is encountered
\newcommand\processSqlitePrompt[1]{%
    \ifcom%                       % In this case, we're already in a command.
    \else                         % Otherwise, we just started a command;
        \global\comtrue%          % set the switch to true and
        {\lst@basicstyle #1}%     % typeset the delimiter in the basic style.
    \fi
    \styleAfterSqlitePrompt%      % In any case, apply the comment style.
}

% Reset the switch at each End-Of-Line character.
\lst@AddToHook{EOL}{\global\comfalse}

\makeatother


\lstnewenvironment{lstSqlite}{%
    \lstset{
        language     = SQL,
        basicstyle   = \ttfamily,
        keywordstyle = \bfseries,
        moredelim    = *[il][\processSqlitePrompt{sqlite>}]{sqlite>},
        moredelim    = *[il][\processSqlitePrompt{\ \ \ ...>}]{\ \ \ ...>},
    }%
}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstSqlite}
sqlite> .open ex2.db
sqlite> select *
   ...> from tab;
Git|1
SQLite|3
\end{lstSqlite}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to turn on/off language settings. Like `{\lst@basicstyle #1}`